# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1-rc with MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: mysql, mysql.data, asp.net-core-2.1, entity-framework-core-2.1

I'm trying to use mysql with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1-rc-final and MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.11 as provider. But when I'm trying to execute the mugrations command i get this exception: 
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommandBuilderFactory..ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.IDiagnosticsLogger`1, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalTypeMapper)'.

This is my IDesignTimeDbContextFactory code implementation:

```
public class DesignLocationFactory:IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<LocationDbContext>
{
    public LocationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<LocationDbContext>();
            builder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;port=3306;user=***;passsword=***;database=locationdb");
        return new LocationDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

Please how can I fix this or at least some sample of how to use with another providers

Comment: same issues with 2.1 release as well. any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, with this provider Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql version 2.1.0-rc1-final everything works perfect.
To install it execute the command:
Install-Package Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -Version 2.1.0-rc1-final

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that 2.1.0-rc1-final resolves this issue. Also, take note of Pomelo's case sensitivity vs Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.

### Pomelo = UseMySql (Sql)

### EntityFrameworkCore = UseMySQL (SQL)

Using Core 2.1

```
Id                                           Versions
--                                           --------
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App                     {2.1.0}
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design {2.1.0}
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools          {2.1.0}
Microsoft.NETCore.App                        {2.1.0}
MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Design        {8.0.11}
MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore               {8.0.11}
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql             {2.1.0-rc1-final}
```